# How can I enable wol on Ubuntu server 16.04?

Tags: server, wakeonlan

I have followed instructions from Ubuntu wiki (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan) with no result.

Worth to note that my NIC is enp0s7 and not eth0, so I replaced eth0 with enp0s7.

At `sudo ethtool enp0s7 | grep -i wake`
I get:

Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g

Also at `/etc/network/interfaces` I put this

```
auto enp0s7
iface enp0s7 inet static
        address 192.168.1.3
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
        up ethtool -s enp0s7 wol g
```

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `sudo ethtool enp0s7 | grep -i wake`

Comment: WOL is enabled, then. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it. The problem was on the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

[How to enable Wake On Lan (WOL) in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764158/how-to-enable-wake-on-lan-wol-in-ubuntu-16-04)

In my case `/etc/default/tlp` was empty, so I just edited `/etc/default/halt` and `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: I have tried this also but with no result.