# How to enable WOL on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: wakeonlan

I've set up the BIOS on my MSI z170 motherboard with

- EUP2013 disabled
- Resume from PCIE

But I still can't make the WOL in my Ubuntu 16.10 work. When I use ethtool to check my NIC, I got the following output without wake-on options:

```
$sudo ethtool enp3s0 
Settings for enp3s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Current message level: 0x000060e4 (24804)
                   link ifup rx_err tx_err hw wol
    Link detected: yes
```

If I don't use sudo, there will be an extra line as follows:

```
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried the approaches [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764158/how-to-enable-wake-on-lan-wol-in-ubuntu-16-04), but obvious, I don't have a battery, so I don't need and have TLP installed. So I can't set `WOL_DISABLE=N`. I can't find /etc/default/halt in my system either, so I can't try to set `NETDOWN=no`.

So what should I do to make my computer wake on LAN?

By the way, in the network-manager -> edit connections -> Ethernet -> Edit -> Ethernet, there is an options for Wake on LAN, but it doesn't work either. And is this new on Ubuntu 16.10? Because I didn't see other people talking about setting WOL in this way.

---

I have some other things work, like

- I used tcpdump to test whether my computer can receive the magic packet, and my computer did receive it
- I set my computer to be able to wake via `ctrl + ESC` when suspended/hibernated, and it worked
- When the computer is shutdown/suspended/hibernated, the light at the LAN are off (I think the system shut it down before the system stopped working. And even if the WOL only works when the computer is shutdown, it should be fine by me).

Answer (score 0):

As I've been fighting with my MSI H97 Gaming 3 mobo for three days now and I've finally found the answer. For me it was bringing together a few things.

One: You have to enable some settings in your bios:

In the motherboard BIOS:

- LAN Option ROM = Enabled
- EuP 2013 = Disabled
- Resume by PCI-E device = Enabled

But after that there seems to be a problem in the driver and as a response, they just cut out the whole WOL support. Never fear however because the internet gives us wonderful people who can solve this for us. In “[Wake-on-LAN broken in alx (AR8161)](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61651#c55)” you can find the auto-installer for Ubuntu (take care to get the right one, scroll down!). Run the setup and you'll be living the life of never having to have to actually get up physically to turn on your computer!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to include the crucial steps of the linked resource in case it changes or disappears? Thanks.