# Wake On Lan not working on HPZ600

Tags: wakeonlan

I tried to make a WOL working on a HP Z600 workstation where Xubuntu 16.04 is installed.

WOL is enabled in the BIOS and ethool shows it as enabled :

```
$ sudo ethtool enp1s0 | grep Wake
     Supports Wake-on: g
     Wake-on: g
```

I checked that Magic Package is received on the workstation sending it from another computer on the same network by looking:

```
$ wakeonlan 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f # from a laptop

$ sudo tcpdump -i enp1s0 port 9 # from the workstation I want to woke up
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp1s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
11:05:44.719516 IP port0129.domain.net.58672 > 255.255.255.255.discard: UDP, length 102
```

I also tried to send the magic package from port 7 with out without using a broadcast IP. In all the case when I have the workstation running I received the magic package.

I also tried to send the magic package with a reverse MAC address as pointed by [How to enable Wake On Lan (WOL) in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764158/how-to-enable-wake-on-lan-wol-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Instead of clicking on the "shutdown button", I tried to shut-down the workstation with:

```
$ sudo shutdown -h now # and also -P
```

In all my test when I send the magic package nothing happen to the workstation.

NIC led are also blinking when the workstation is down.

Any clue/idea to unlock the situation?

Comment: Do you have TLP installed? It has a [config switch](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#networking) that disables WOL by default (to save energy). – Oh. Just seen you're talking about a workstation. Then likely TLP is _not_ installed. Forget about it.

Comment: @PerlDuck Yes it's a workstation and `tlp` is not installed: `$ apt list --installed | grep tlp` returns nothing.