# An `ethtool` and `wakeonlan` all-in-one package?

Tags: networking, software-installation, wakeonlan

I've just setup my old laptop to wake up / power on / resume from suspend controlled by my primary laptop. In the process I had to install two different packages:

```
sudo apt install ethtool
sudo apt install wakeonlan
```

Is there a package that accomplishes both or maybe in conjunction with preinstalled software only one package is needed?

Comment: Why is it a problem to install two packages? If the wakeonlan package needs ethtool it will pull it automatically when apt calculate dependencies. Splitting functionallity out in more packages and depending on others, makes package size smaller and speeds up installation. It also reduces total installed size since more packages can share libraries and other backends.

Answer (score 2):

The only package I see that currently (20.04) install those two at the same time is:

```
shutdown-at-night
```

It [depends on other software](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/shutdown-at-night), that could in turn depend on other software. Exactly what's going to be installed, besides `ethtool` and `wakeonlan` depends on your current set of packages.

To find that out I ran:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends ethtool | egrep "^[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]]"|sort > /tmp/ethtool.rdep
$ apt-cache rdepends wakeonlan | egrep "^[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]]"|sort > /tmp/wakeonlan.rdep
$ comm -1 -2 /tmp/ethtool.rdep /tmp/wakeonlan.rdep
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install `ethtool` to enable "wake on LAN" feature of your NIC on Ubuntu. If you have `systemd`, then you can look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006099/331100) answer. `wakeonlan` utility is still needed on your primary laptop.