# Wake On Lan UBUNTU 18.04 - DELL OptiPlex

Tags: 18.04, dell, remote-desktop, wakeonlan, anydesk

How to enable Wake on Lan on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?
I tried what's in this question: [How to enable Wake On Lan (WOL) in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764158/how-to-enable-wake-on-lan-wol-in-ubuntu-16-04)

But it did'nt work. Thanks in advance...
**Edit:** Optiplex model is 5050

Comment: There may be a setting you need to enable in your BIOS. Under power management maybe? https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-nz/000134760/optiplex-xe2-unable-to-wake-on-lan-with-bios-version-a05-installed

Comment: Dell OptiPlex is rather vague... I've access to >10 of those; and they aren't all the same; some are easy to achieve exactly what you want, others using the same settings don't wake up; but given you're asking about machines that started being produced in 1993 & continue today - the term optiplex isn't helpful.

Comment: It's Optiplex 5050.